# position_in_pixel * DPI

Tags: dpi, theory

There's a software who export content as image and provide a metadata files giving the X/Y position and X/Y distance from those points to box elements within the image.

In the code, all thoses values are computed as: "coordinate_in_pixel * dpi"

My question: I really don't get what "coordinate_in_pixel * dpi" should mean, as dpi don't relate to pixel as in the previous formula. After looking and asking many people, it makes no sense for me and for the few who get a bit my misunderstanding (all graphist/prepress/etc) to have the previous formula, what am I missing ? What is expressed by that computing ? As it is from an open source software with others exploiting those values, I'm wondering what is expressed by that formula and that I'm missing.

Comment: I realize there may be a language barrier, but I have no clue what is being asked.

Comment: does the formula (distance_in_pixel *  dpi) means something ? 
what does the result represent ? (for me there's a logical error in the previous, but  before asserting they're dumb, I really want to make sure  I'm not the one missing something ^^)

Comment: Also edited to remove not pertinent parts and make what I ask more clear

Comment: DPI traditionally is an acronym for **Dots Per Inch** and has no relation to any "distance". At least in the design/printing industry. I have never seen "DPI" represent *any* sort of distance measurement.

Comment: Thanks! so you would agree that it's really "strange", to say the least, that they multiply those pixel coordinates by the dpi value of the document it's refering to? As it makes no real sense. It's clearly the Dots Per Inch value that is used, as the factor comes from a dpi settings in the software config name "DPI" with a 300 default value. Can send the bit of code where the dpi factor is applied to the pixel coordonates, but there's really nothing more to see than what I explained. If by any chance, they misused DPI acronym instead of PPI, would that change something? Or make more sense?

Comment: A coordinate given in pixels *divided* by the DPI value (if that is meant to be pixels per inch, a quite common ambiguity) would give the coordinates in inches. Given that the source is available, maybe you could link to some example cases where this is computed?

Comment: Thanks ! I would also have no issue if it was a division, as it would have given the distance in inch based on the PPI.
The source code for this is available on github, line 92: https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/blob/c9f8a138529c15bf9d096e53a4a2af14af32ae11/mscore/savePositions.cpp
Also, they compute that value a bit strangely (line 57), they take the DPI settings configured by the user divide it by the internal DPI setting  and multiply by12 (what is  that 12?) But yet, the var is still named ndpi.

Comment: Don't want  to jump on the "evil company wagon", but knowing this feature might only be used by the commercial exploitant of the software, might in the end just be really specific to their needs and the way they handle positionning. Also, that part of the software is really poorly documented (would say not, as I had to dig in the code to understand how to use the computed values), so... who knows what could be the intent :/

Comment: Also, if I consider the comment stating "output in 100 dpi", and update the dpi of the image gile it's related with to 100dpi, the values given in the metadata files giving the x/y/sx/sy positions dont align, wathever the units with a ruler in an image editing software.

Comment: regarding the previous comment, also tried with 100 dpcm, "same result", as it don't match what it's supposed to match, wathever the ruler unit (can't edit previous mesage anymore)

Comment: To me it seems like ndpi is a scaling factor. I wouldn't be surprised if its purpose was mostly to adjust an internal model of the layout to the configurable final output image size. But this makes a question that is much more appropriate for the software authors to answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael ! Will do on their forum, just to understand what was done there, in a way, I have the workaround. Thanks a lot for your time, opinion and answers !

Comment: Those who have never worked in printing or on digital artwork destined for printing, are often completely unaware of the usage of DPI in its traditional form. Even some mobile manufacturers have incorrectly used DPI to mean Density Pixels per Inch - which merely confuses things further.

Comment: from what I found on their forums etc, it's an "unmaintained" feature, unknown by most devs, dating from a decade ago, but there's still "legacy" clients using it, with some having issue and the dev team unable to fix(15yo project). It turns out I'm not the only one having issue understanding that part, it's been updated over time to "work" but, imho, with "low understanding" of the logic behind (most updates for the past years comes from "general refactoring"). It's an open source project, so I'll not be too harsh neither, yet, you both helped me to decide it was something "to fix". Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula makes indeed no sense and been confirmed with the developers to be result of unmaintained features being updated to allow compilation and updated over large scale refactoring with low regard to initial logic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101257)

Comment: I'm the author and that's the answer: "it doesn't make any sense" ^^
My question was "what does that means ?", the answer is "nothing outside answering to specific needs that don't rely on any known concept of infographic" as the formula, indeed, is problematic.

Comment: @Wolff I edited it to reflect that, do you consider the current answer valid and understandable enough ?

Comment: Sure, that was what I meant .